# PHPDevKit for QBDesktop

Tags: php, quickbooks

We are trying to implement the PHPDevKit to integrate QB Desktop with our PHP application. Should we keep separate web connector files (server) for import and export? Sample web connector files have them as separated for import and export also it has request and response functions in it. Not sure it is required to keep them in web connector files or can move it as separate files?

Can someone share the best folder structure to keep all required files to easily readable?

Comment: Post your code. Also, your question sounds _extremely_ subjective. It's just PHP. You can include whatever you want and put your functions where-ever you want and organize your files however you want.

Comment: I got it. An another question. How to import (QB->MySQL) only updated records from QB (SO, Estimate or Invoice) since we ran sync last time?

Comment: Again, post your code and show us what you've tried so far. We can't help you if we can't see what you're doing.